# Cannot read csv file from dask, except if loaded from pandas first

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a very large csv data file that is partitioned into smaller chunks/part. But pandas doesn't seem a good idea if you're trying to load millions or more rows, because it's essentially loaded into your RAM (I have tried this and the kernel just died instead). So, I am thinking of using Dask. Now I am familiar with pandas, but not with dask. There doesn't seem a lot of tutorial about it either.

When I am trying to load one part of the csv file (around 60.000~ rows) with pandas, it still works fine. The problem is when I tried to load all the parts (hundreds of them). I want to use Dask for that, but even loading one part still failed.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

ddf = dd.read_csv("path/part-000", header=None, blocksize=None)
```

When I tried the above code, it seems to work fine at first, but all the code I did after that always results in error. I also can't seem to put npartitions when I read the file directly from dask.

```
len(ddf)

ValueError: Mismatched dtypes found in `pd.read_csv`/`pd.read_table`.

+--------+--------+----------+
| Column | Found  | Expected |
+--------+--------+----------+
| 1      | object | float64  |
| 2      | object | float64  |
| 4      | object | int64    |
+--------+--------+----------+
```

So I loaded it from pandas first then convert it to dask.

```
df = pd.read_csv("path/part-000", header=None)
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=64)
```

It works, but I don't like this approach, since like I said I have millions of rows partitioned into smaller chunks/parts, so loading it to pandas then converting it to dask doesn't sound too efficient.

So my questions can be summed up into this.

1. How do I load the file directly to Dask while also using parameter like `blocksize` or `npartitions`?
2. How do I load a lot of files to Dask? In pandas, I usually use the `append()` function, but I have no idea if it's the right approach here.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I face the same error when dd.read_csv(filename, header=9). It works with pandas but not dask dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the error message that Dask gives you provides a `dtype=` keyword to provide to your read_csv call to make sure that things work (it seems like you cut this off in this question).  It probably looks like the following:

```
dtypes={1: object, 2: object, 4:object}
```

If you include the provided line in your read_csv call then things should work.

Comment: thanks for your response. Where do I put that parameter? I tried `ddf = dd.read_csv("path/part-000", header=None, dtypes={1: object, 2: object,3:object, 4:object,5: object, 6:object})`  and still got an error. `TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtypes'`.

Comment: See the pandas.read_csv docstring for more information on allowed keyword arguments.  It's possible that I chose the wrong name.